# Does heap memory gets freed when I restart my PC?

Tags: memory-leaks

I have been started learning C++. Now when I came across dynamic memory allocation I heard of pointers...
But in this concept there is a problem of memory leak.
So my confusion is...
When we ***restart*** our ***PC***, does **heap** memory gets **freed**, which remained allocated while the program's run ?

Comment: Pretty much *everything* gets freed when you restart the PC. Well, except disk space. So, all *memory,* yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution to this problem.

**When you restart your PC, all the problem of memory leak is solved by your operating system.**

So, don't worry, operating systems these days are smart enough to solve such issues by themselves.
If your are facing any *lag* in your system. **Just restart your PC**. All the memory will be freed!!

Comment: To be precise: The impact of a memory-leak is solved. Not the cause. But in that case it is more or less the same.